# Do my items drop when I quit?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I'm wondering if items drop when you quit in Fortnite Battle Royale. I want to know if your items drop when you randomly decide to quit, and when you're knocked, and you quit before you run out of health. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your character dies when you quit a match in progress, and all your items are dropped as usual.